# How to set noatime for startup drive in Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, ssd

I've followed instructions to [set the noatime flag in Lion](http://blog.alutam.com/2012/04/01/optimizing-macos-x-lion-for-ssd/#noatime) so I can reduce SSD usage but it isn't working for me on Mountain Lion.

I'm still seeing this after restarting:

```
$ mount | grep " / "
/dev/disk0s2 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
```

Has anyone got any suggestions how to mount the startup drive with mount flag noatime?

Comment: What happens if you just run `sudo mount -vuwo noatime /` from the command line? It might produce an informative error message.

Comment: it gives no error, output shows noatime is enabled but it only lasts until the next restart, so it needs to be scheduled I guess.

Comment: Yeah, I knew it had to be scheduled. I asked because I wanted to know if it was the command that had failed. But as you found out, it was the scheduling that didn't work.

Comment: It will work see my expanded answer > http://superuser.com/questions/487926/how-do-i-use-noatime-with-filevault-2-fde-on-mountain-lion/508286#508286

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I think I've got it working.

Add the file `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.nullvision.noatime.plist` with contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
        "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.nullvision.noatime</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>mount</string>
            <string>-vuwo</string>
            <string>noatime</string>
            <string>/</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Run these:

- `sudo chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.nullvision.noatime.plist`
- `sudo chmod 644 /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.nullvision.noatime.plist`
- `sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.nullvision.noatime.plist`

The permissions have to be set to that for `launchctl` not to complain.

Then you've got this on restart:

```
$ mount | grep " / "
/dev/disk0s2 on / (hfs, local, journaled, noatime)
```

You can check if it runs by looking in the console:

```
29/07/12 2:55:45.334 PM sudo[978]:     Aram : TTY=ttys000 ; PWD=/Library/LaunchDaemons ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.nullvision.noatime.plist
```

Comment: I think it's okay for you to accept your own answer. It won't give you any reputation, for obvious reason, but it marks the question as solved.

Comment: says I have to wait till tomorrow, probably to ensure other answers are provided if the OP thinks they've got it when they don't

Comment: A small note, BTW: This runs the command with the `v` flag, but that just turns on verbosity. Which is hardly useful in a `launchd`-controlled job. I don't think it will even find its way into a log file?

Comment: Yeah it puts it in the console, see my update

Comment: That console message is from `sudo`, run in your terminal. The output from the `mount` command run by `launchd` is what I was referring to. Does it show up too?

Answer (score 2):

The tool [Chameleon SSD Optimizer](http://chameleon.alessandroboschini.it/index.php) will work for this and it also enables TRIM. I did a lot of research and most were directing to TRIM Enabler. Then, I read few but VERY good news about this one and opted for it as it seemed newer, more stable and with no or fewer bugs.

I installed did it on my iMac (2,5 GHz i5, 16GB Ram, OCZ Vertex3 120GB SSD [boot disk] + original 500GB HD) running OS X 10.7.5. Although it was already a nice fast machine, this made things feel even faster. I use my iMac for photo and video editing with Adobe Packages and everything's stable with this addition.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same problem in ML.  I followed the instructions you linked to and kept getting the same result as you.

```
Davids-MacBook-Pro:~ davidsilver$ mount | grep " / "
/dev/disk0s2 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
```

However, Harald Hanche-Olsen's recommendation to run `sudo mount -vuwo noatime /` seemed to correct the problem.

```
Davids-MacBook-Pro:~ davidsilver$ mount | grep " / "
/dev/disk0s2 on / (hfs, local, journaled, noatime)
```

Comment: Ah! It worked but as I feared the flag is reset on restart. It seems the plist isn't getting executed at startup. You can apparently check for com.nullvision in the console if it runs.

Comment: See my answer...

Comment: I did as you said above, however I still get /dev/disk0s2 on / (hfs, local, journaled)

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems and had do to some additional steps

- change the permission of /Library/LaunchDaemons to 777
- copy an existant plist as com.nullvision.noatime.plist
- edit it's content as mentioned above and save it
- change the ownership and permission as mentioned above
- run launchctl as mentioned above
- change back the permission of /Library/LaunchDaemons to 755
- reboot and check with mount | grep " / "

Comment: Do NOT recommend escalated privileges of 0777. Files in LaunchDaemons should never be higher than 0644. The ownership of the file (with group) would be: root:wheel (something you actually don't list, but strangely reference).